# Is there a way for me to determine which program runs the fastest using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a new programmer and for a school assignment I had to write a program (Java) that prints out the first 1000 perfect squares. I had to do this using three different kinds of loops: while, do-while, for. I know that when you run the program it says in the output log the amount of time it has taken to run the program, but I need to determine which loop(s) run faster than the other(s). I get 0 seconds for each different kind of loop, but obviously they will be executed at different speeds and I want to know if there is a way for me to determine which actually runs the fastest. Does Netbeans have a tool for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not implement a simple algorithm in java that calculates the running time? :)

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// insert your program here

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long total = end - start;
System.out.println("Program finished in " + total + " milliseconds.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do something like this:  

        //Put this before the loop, time in which the algorithm starts
        long start= System.currentTimeMillis();

        //Time after the algorithm has finished, end of the loop
        long end= System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Total time for the algorithm to complete
        long total=end -start;
        System.out.println("Total time in milliseconds:" + total);
```